Relation between a diagonal element of a density matrix and the off-diagonal elements in the same row/column
In a density matrix $\rho=(\rho_{ij})$, the diagonal elements $\rho_{jj}$ contains the information about the probability $|\rho_{jj}|^2$ that the $j$-th eigenstate is occupied by the system. Meanwhile, the off-diagonal elements $\rho_{i,j\neq i}$ tells us the coherence between the $i$-th and the $j$-th eigenstate.
My intuition tells me something like this:
$\quad$ If the $i$-th eigenstate is not occupied, then there is no coherence between that eigenstate and the other possible eigenstates of the system.
In other words, here I claim that for a given $i$, the elements $\rho_{i,j\neq i}$ must be zero when $\rho_{ii}$ is zero.
Here is one example I can think of. Suppose we have an $N$ level system whose possible eigenstates are described by the number states $\left|n\right\rangle;n=0,1,\dots,(N-1)$. Suppose now that the system occupies a pure state that is a superposition of every possible state except for the $k$-th state, i.e. $\left|\psi\right\rangle=\sum_{i\neq k}c_i\left|i\right\rangle$. The corresponding density matrix $\rho=\left|\psi\right\rangle\left\langle\psi\right|=\sum_{i,j\neq k}c_ic_j^*\left|i\right\rangle\left\langle j \right|$ evidently has $\rho_{kj}=0$. The $k$-th eigenstate is not occupied, and the corresponding row and column in the density matrix are zero.
My question is: is this generally true, even for mixed states?
In a broader picture, I wonder if the value of the diagonal element $\rho_{ii}$ determines the values of the off-diagonal elements $\rho_{i,j\neq i}$ in the same row/column. I reckon that this knowledge may be useful when, for example, I can know that a certain state is reached simply by looking at the values of the diagonal entries.

Exact duplicate: Relationships between elements in the density matrix
